# How to make ft-syntax-omni work with Jade?

Tags: vim, autocomplete, pug, omnicomplete

Well, `ft-syntax-omni` is supposed to provide omni autocompletion based on syntax highlighting, I guess. However it does not work with [vim-jade](https://github.com/digitaltoad/vim-jade) plugin. For example, typing `tabl` followed by hitting `<C-x><C-o>` says `Omni completion (^O^N^P) Pattern not found`.

Is there any way to make `ft-syntax-omni` work properly with [vim-jade](https://github.com/digitaltoad/vim-jade) plugin?

Comment: Seems finally we have got a dedicated pug (formerly jade) completion plugin: [vim-pug-complete](https://github.com/dNitro/vim-pug-complete)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax omnicompletion works best with plain syntax *keywords*. The Java syntax script defines very few. Your example `tabl` is not contained in it at all, that's why there's no completion for it. Also, by default, the syntax omnicompletion only considers syntax groups that start with the filetype (`jade`), but this particular syntax mainly includes other syntaxes (e.g. `html`).

I see syntax omnicompletion as a fallback for obscure filetypes. If you regularly use a language, find a dedicated completion, or write one yourself!